# Discontinuous function with continuous inverse

Tags: real-analysis, functions

My textbook asks to provide an example of a discontinuous function with continuous inverse. It also provides an answer which is $x + sign(x)$.

But I don't get why its inverse is continuous. It's not just discontinuous, it's even undefined on (-1,0) and (0,1). I'd appreciate your help in either understanding why is this example is correct, or getting another example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f(t) = t+\mbox{ signum} (t)$$ then $$f^{-1} (t) =\begin{cases} t-1 \mbox{ if } t>1 \\0  \mbox{ if } t=0\\ t+1 \mbox{ if } t<-1\end{cases}$$ and $f^{-1} $ is obviously continuous.

Comment: What about $t=0$? I think, it's main part.

Comment: $t=0$ is an isolated point of the domain of the function $f^{-1} .$ Every function is continuous at isolated point of its domain.

Comment: It's kind of cheating, isn't it? When I read the problem the first time, I thought I was supposed to find function such that its inverse somehow fill the "gaps" made in the range of discontinuous function.

Comment: It's not a kind of cheating. It's good example to show that intuitions and mathematical definitions are two different things. Although intuition it is a very important thing in mathematics.

Comment: @MotylaNogaTomkaMazura, really, I forgot about domain of $f^{-1}$